# Unable to change the background color of the selected li item in a UL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-lists

I need your help,

How can I change the background (using jQuery) of the selected LI item in my UL list. As it is right now, the only thing being changed is the entire background of my list. One last thing to note is that the color should be defaulted to white, should a new LI item be selected.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script> 
<head>

<style type="text/css">
#container {
    width: 200px;
}
#list1 {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 100%;
}
#list1 ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 3px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
#list1 li {
    cursor: default;
}
.selected {
    background: blue;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {

$('#list1').click(function(){
  var that = $(this);
  that.closest('li').find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
  that.addClass('selected');
});

}
</script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="container">
    <div id="list1">
        <ul>
          <li>Coffee</li>
          <li>Tea</li>
          <li>Milk</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Attach the click event handler to the list items, no the parent div. `that.addClass('selected')` will always add the class to the parent div as you have it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var $items = $('#list1 li').click(function() {
    $items.removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

There's no reason to keep selecting new elements for this task. Simply create a collection of all the list items (`$items)`, and reuse it for removing the `selected` class from the previous item.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `.closest()` here since `#list1` is the ancestor of your `li`:

```
that.find('li.selected').removeClass('selected');
```

But actually, I think what you're trying to do is to add `.active` to clicked `li` and remove this `active` class from the other `li`, if that is the case then you can do:

```
$('#list1 ul li').click(function () {
    $('#list1 ul li').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7njw2/)**